# okular (snap) print-preview/print-to-pdf does not work

Tags: printing, snap, okular

I run 18.04.1-Ubuntu and have installed okular using snap

```
 okular  19.04.2  63   stable    kde✓
```

I try to export to pdf such that all annotations will be integrated 
such that they cannot be edited anymore. For this I tried to print to pdf file. When I select print to file in the print dialog, select a file and then print  no file is created.

A further problem seems to be that when selecting okular->file->print-preview okular opens a print-preview window containing only the text

```
 could not load print preview part
```

Okular has the following snap connections established

```
(~) 562> snap connections okular 
Interface                             Plug                          Slot                                                  Notes
content[kde-frameworks-5-core18-all]  okular:kde-frameworks-5-plug  kde-frameworks-5-core18:kde-frameworks-5-core18-slot  -
cups-control                          okular:cups-control           :cups-control                                         -
dbus                                  -                             okular:session-dbus-interface                         -
desktop                               okular:desktop                :desktop                                              -
desktop-legacy                        okular:desktop-legacy         :desktop-legacy                                       -
home                                  okular:home                   :home                                                 -
network                               okular:network                :network                                              -
network-bind                          okular:network-bind           :network-bind                                         -
opengl                                okular:opengl                 :opengl                                               -
pulseaudio                            okular:pulseaudio             :pulseaudio                                           -
unity7                                okular:unity7                 :unity7                                               -
x11                                   okular:x11                    :x11                                                  -
```