# okular stamps not visible in other pdf viewers

Tags: pdf, okular

I run 18.04.1-Ubuntu and have installed okular using snap

```
 okular  19.04.2  63   stable    kde✓
```

I'd like to create image signature stamps with okular like described here

[How to add a Signature stamp to Okular](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132658/how-to-add-a-signature-stamp-to-okular/1132705#1132705)

I successfully added an image signature to my pdf document, and can save and reopen it with okular without problem.

Unfortunately no other pdf viewer on my system. Neither Evince document viewer (3.28.4), nor Atril Document Viewer (1.20.1), nor Xournal (0.4.8) see the signature. This does not seem to be a problem with my signature image, all the other default stamps I have tried are not seen by other 
viewers.

Is there any way that okular can create these stamps in a way other applications can see them? Note that I tried printing to pdf but this does not work as explained here

[okular (snap) print-preview/print-to-pdf does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205392/okular-snap-print-preview-print-to-pdf-does-not-work)

Comment: I am in my phone right now. But this is a reported bug in Okular. For the time being  I use xournal for this purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @Bruni's comment. I now found the bug report https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383651  that dates from 2017 and seems still not resolved.

Searching the web before I had found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34053/are-there-any-full-featured-pdf-readers-that-integrate-comment-function this thread with an answer from **2013** telling that stamps are not saved in a way they are visible for other software.

So the answer to my question is: **no, up to today January 2020 there is no way okular can safe stamps in a way other pdf readers can read it**. Interestingly, also printing it the document will not show the image stamp. So basically it is impossible to store a signature image into a pdf file with okular and xournal has to be used.

Note that google displays the bug 383651 rather high in its results for "okular stamp problem", but neither Qwant nor DuckDuckGo (search engines I use) do show it at all. All however come up with the present AskUbuntu question. So I add the answer that I was searching for here for others not using google's search egine to find it.

Comment: So is there any way other PDF reader that allow to add signature stamps and export and/or print it on Linux/Ubuntu platforms ?

Comment: For the moment I still use "xournal" which I mentioned already in the answer and that was proposed by Bruni in the comment to my question.

Comment: The [mentioned bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383651) was solved in Okular 21.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

That was because of a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383651) that was solved in Okular 21.12.0.